# Anyone have a good article on how to setup an AD Lab in VMWARE Workstation for Home Lab?

Tags: windows, virtualization

I am a developer.
Windows experienced, Linux experienced.
I am *Not* a Sysadmin.

I would like to play around with Active Directory on my home PC.

I have a Nehalem-based Xeon with 12 gigs of memory, so I was hoping to hoist up a few VM's (I have VMWare 7 Workstation) to get the job done.

Since I am not an admin, I need a little more detail than articles I have found.

Anyone have any recommended sites?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some links to articles you could need:

- [How To Create A Network Test Lab With VMware](http://www.petri.co.il/virtual_create_network_testlab_vmware.htm)
- Microsoft Support: [Considerations when hosting Active Directory domain controller in virtual hosting environments](http://support.microsoft.com/?scid=kb%3Ben-us%3B888794)
- [Building a Windows Server 2008 virtual test lab](http://searchwindowsserver.techtarget.com/tip/0,289483,sid68_gci1267878,00.html)

Answer (score 0):

[How do I install Active Directory on my Windows Server 2003 server?](http://www.petri.co.il/how_to_install_active_directory_on_windows_2003.htm)  (from www.petri.co.il)